# ArcGIS Raster Calculator Con-Statement

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, map-algebra, con

I am trying to manipulate bad pixel values in a raster by using the Con-Statement via ArcPy. Using the build-in Map Algebra function "Raster Calculator", the results are good. To transfer the work flow to a script, the outcome is different. The pixel values should be between [-1;1].

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = out_folder #path to my folder containing the raster files
list = arcpy.ListFiles('*.tif')
for ras in list:
     outras1 = Con(ras > 1, 1, ras)
     outras2 = Con(outras1 < -1, -1, outras1)
     outras2.save(ras + '_mod.tif')
```

Can you tell, what I am doing wrong?

The results show only pixel values of 1. Additional information: I have large areas of NoData values in my raster.

Comment: Otherwise, the combination of the Con statement:    outras1 = Con(ras > 1, 1, Con(ras < -1.0,-1.0, ras))   produces the same result.

Comment: Try r=arcpy.Raster(ras), because this will create raster from string.

Comment: Thankyou for the "object" reference to this process. I am converting pixels with multiple elevation values to the maximum elevation found for hundreds of polygon segments that cross over culverts. Sample code. rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters(raspref+"*") print "rasterlist= ",rasterlist for i in rasterlist: inputraster = i print "inputraster = ",inputraster print "Getting MAXIMUM elevation value in DEM" raster = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (inputraster, "MAXIMUM") elevMax = float(raster.getOutput(0)) print "MAXIMUM elevation for", inputraster, "= ", elevMax rast = arcpy.Raster(inputrast

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127702)

Answer (score 3):

@FelixIP comment is correct, you need to convert your raster file to a raster object using [arcpy.Raster()](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/raster-object.htm) before using [Con()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm).

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"F:\Test\Test\FolderName"

ext_out = arcpy.CheckOutExtension("SPATIAL")

raslist = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')

for ras in raslist:
    raster = arcpy.Raster(ras)

    ras_con = Con(raster < -1, -1, Con(raster > 1, 1,raster))
    ras_con.save(ras[:-4]+"_Final.tif")
```

Comment: This post is way more informative than any of the official Esri documentation I've read on using the raster calculator in Python. Thank you!